# Identificar en una data las variables que son tipo factor en R

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Necesito un ciclo que me recorra un base de datos y me identifique las variables que tengo que cambiar a tipo factor, las que tengas 0 y 1 por que hay unas variables que solo tienen 0 o 1 esas las necesito dejar numéricas (ya que hay unas variables que carecen del otro factor y la función lm solo me recibe variables con mas de dos factores)

Por ejemplo, tenemos los siguientes datos que podemos leer desde un base de datos, un excel, un csv:

```
txt <- "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
1,0,100,1,alto
1,1,101,0,medio
0,0,200,1,alto
1,1,101,1,bajo
"
df <- as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = ",", header=TRUE))
```

Si revisamos el `data.frame` vemos que las columnas tipo caracter son convertidas a `factor`

```
> class(df$c5)
[1] "factor"
```

Sin embargo los valores numéricos se mantienen como tales, por ejemplo:

```
> class(df$c3)
[1] "factor"
```

Quisiera poder especificar que columnas pasar a `factor`.

Comment: Bienvenida Laura, te sugiero que edites la pregunta ya que no queda claro lo que preguntas y eventualmente será cerrada. Agrega en lo posible un ejemplo de código o una muestra de los datos. Cuando hablas de base de datos? a que te refieres, a un data.frame? a una tabla?

Comment: Hola es un data. frame.... Lo que necesito específicamente es realiar un ciclo que me convierta las variables a factor, no todas las del data.frame sino las que sean necesarias

Comment: Laura, voy a editar tu pregunta agregando un ejemplo mínimo con esto último que comentas, a ver si se corresponde con lo que buscas.

Comment: Tengo por ejemplo v1=0,1,1,0,1,0 y v2=0,0,0,0,0,0 necesito un ciclo que me recorra filas y columnas y me cambie la variable 1 a factor pero la dos que me la deje numérica, si soy clara, es que no se que  otra forma explicar.... tengo esto pero no se si estoy bien for (i in 1:ncol(Datos)) {
  aux<-TRUE
  for (j in 1:nrow(Datos)) {
    if(Datos[j,i]!=1 && Datos[j,i]!=0){
      aux<-FALSE
      break
    }
    
  }
  if(aux==TRUE){
    
    Datos[,i]<- lapply(Datos[,i], as.factor)
  }
}

Comment: Creo que te entiendo, en un ratito te armo una respuesta

Comment: Mil gracias, estoy super complicada con eso

Answer (score 1):

Si tenemos un conjunto grande de columnas/variables y queremos convertir alguna de ellas en un factor y otras no, la forma más sencilla es armar un vector de columnas a convertir. Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente `data.frame`

```
txt <- "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
1,0,100,1,alto, 0
1,1,101,0,medio, 0
0,0,200,1,alto, 0
1,1,101,1,bajo, 0
"

df <- as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = ",", header=TRUE))
```

Inspeccionando:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ c1: int  1 1 0 1
 $ c2: int  0 1 0 1
 $ c3: int  100 101 200 101
 $ c4: int  1 0 1 1
 $ c5: Factor w/ 3 levels "alto","bajo",..: 1 3 1 2
 $ c6: int  0 0 0 0
```

No todas las variables son `factor`, por defecto solo las que son tipos cadena. Ahora bien, supongamos que queremos pasar a `factor` las columnas 1,2,3,4 y no la 6, ni la 5 que ya es `factor`. Esto lo podemos resolver así:

```
col.to.factor <- c(1,2,3,4)
df[col.to.factor] <- lapply(df[col.to.factor], as.factor)
```

El resultado:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ c1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2
 $ c2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2
 $ c3: Factor w/ 3 levels "100","101","200": 1 2 3 2
 $ c4: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2
 $ c5: Factor w/ 3 levels "alto","bajo",..: 1 3 1 2
 $ c6: int  0 0 0 0
```

Claramente vemos que hemos dejado solo la columna/variable `c6` como entero y el resto las hemos convertido a `factor`. Otra forma más interesante sería, por ejemplo: convertir todas las variables/columnas que tengan solo 1 y 0 en `factor` de forma automática y el resto dejarlas como están:

Primero generamos un vector lógico `apply.factor` que nos dice que columnas tienen solo 1 y 0:

```
apply.factor <- sapply(df, function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(levels(as.factor(x)),as.vector(as.factor(c("0", "1"))))))
> apply.factor
   c1    c2    c3    c4    c5    c6 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Lo importante es: `as.vector(as.factor(c("0", "1")))` que arma la muestra de valores que queremos verificar en una columna/variable, obviamente se puede modificar por lo que necesitemos para hacer una comparación de cada columna con este mismo `vector.

Luego en `col.to.factor` generamos el vector con los índices de columnas que vamos a convertir (las columnas que cumplieron nuestro criterio)

```
col.to.factor <- seq(length(apply.factor))[apply.factor]
> col.to.factor
[1] 1 2 4
```

Y por último aplicamos la conversión solo sobre las columnas elegidas

```
df[col.to.factor] <- lapply(df[col.to.factor], as.factor)
```

Resumiendo todo:

```
> apply.factor <- sapply(df, function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(levels(as.factor(x)),as.vector(as.factor(c("0", "1"))))))
> col.to.factor <- seq(length(apply.factor))[apply.factor]
> df[col.to.factor] <- lapply(df[col.to.factor], as.factor)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ c1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 1 2
 $ c2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2
 $ c3: int  100 101 200 101
 $ c4: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2
 $ c5: Factor w/ 3 levels "alto","bajo",..: 1 3 1 2
 $ c6: int  0 0 0 0
```

Vemos entonces que hemos convertido en `factor` las columnas que queríamos.

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Mil gracias, esta genial

Answer (score 1):

Usando la librería `dyplr::` se puede hacer con la función `mutate_if()`, que cambia todas las columnas de un data.frame que cumplen con determinada condición aplicándoles una función.

```
#Cargo la librería
library(dplyr) 

#Uso los datos que preparó Patricio

txt <- "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
1,0,100,1,alto, 0
1,1,101,0,medio, 0
0,0,200,1,alto, 0
1,1,101,1,bajo, 0"
df <- as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection(txt), sep = ",", header=TRUE))


# La siguiente línea hace todo el trabajo:

mutate_if(df, df[1,]==1 | df[1,]==0, as.factor)
```

`mutate_if()` lleva tres argumentos: los datos, la condición y la función que vamos a aplicar cuando se cumple la condición. En este caso:

- los datos son `df`
- la condición es que la primera fila de `df` sea igual a 1 **o** igual a 0, eso hace `|`.

  > Cuidado: el resultado de la evaluación depende unicamente de la información en la primera fila y podría haber ambigüedades. Digamos que tenés una variable numérica que NO querés convertir a factor y por casualidad comienza con 0 o 1: en ese caso también se convertiría a factor.
- la función es `as.factor`, que coerciona la columna al tipo factor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor sería importar directamente los datos con el tipo correcto. Para esto es muy útil el paquete `readr` que es parte del `tidyverse`, un conjunto de paquetes muy bueno que te recomiendo explorar.

Con readr hay una serie de funciones que comienzan con read_ y que permiten importar datos en forma de tibbles.Tibble es otro tipo de dato muy similar al dataframe y que se puede usar exactamente igual pero tiene algunas ventajas, más info: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html.

Lo interesante de estas funciones es que determinan el tipo de datos a partir de las primeras observaciones de cada columna y no asumen el tipo factor cuando hay texto, pero tambien permiten especificar el tipo para cada columna del dataframe de la siguiente manera:

```
library(readr)

txt <- "c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
1,0,100,1,alto
1,1,101,0,medio
0,0,200,1,alto
1,1,101,1,bajo
"
df <-read_delim(file = txt, 
                delim = ',',
                col_types = cols(c5 = col_factor(levels = NULL))
                )
```

En este caso solo estamos convirtiendo a factor la columna c5 y al poner `levels = NULL` los niveles del factor son tomados de los valores únicos de c5.

Si observamos df, vemos que sólo c5 es de tipo factor. Se muestra de esta forma porque es un tibble y no un dataframe:

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     c1    c2    c3    c4     c5
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <fctr>
1     1     0   100     1   alto
2     1     1   101     0  medio
3     0     0   200     1   alto
4     1     1   101     1   bajo

> str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ c1: int  1 1 0 1
 $ c2: int  0 1 0 1
 $ c3: int  100 101 200 101
 $ c4: int  1 0 1 1
 $ c5: Factor w/ 3 levels "alto","medio",..: 1 2 1 3
```